# How should I continue this code? What keyword should I use for the 2nd part of this assignment?

Tags: c, prompt

I am writing a code that initially displays my credentials then I am supposed to prompt the user to enter values for certain variables. I do not know how to finish the second part of the program. I don't know whether to use a specific keyword for starting the second part of the program. I tried to attempt to use (int main(void)) again after the } but my program failed. What do I use instead of (int main(void))?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    printf("name\n");
    printf("email\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(void)

{
    printf(Enter value for a(in feet): \n");
    scanf(%f\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start with an opening quote on `printf(Enter`. Followed by a *different program*. You can't have two `main` entry points in a program; only one. I somehow suspect you need one program that does *both* however, in the *same* `main()`.

Comment: Yes, put both in the same main(). Or, if you want to make the distinction clear, put each in a subroutine invoked from main(). Though in fact you aren't accomplishing the first part of the assignment -- you're printing simple prompts, but you aren't accepting the prompted-for values from the user, and generally "prompt for" implies "and accept".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up [functions in C](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson4.html).  In fact reading the first few pages of a  [C tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html) will take you a long way.  In short a function does some operation then returns the result or it may not return anything.  So lets break down what you've got and what it does.

When you write `int main(void)` you're telling the compiler that you have a function that returns an integer (that's the `int` part).  The name of this function is `main`.  And you do not need to provide it anything to get started (`void`).  You can't have more than one function of the same name because the compiler doesn't know which to use.  `main` is a special function that is called automatically when the program runs.

To prompt a user to input a value, you need to print the prompt (which you almost did with `printf(Enter value for a(in feet): \n");` except you forgot `"` before Enter).  Then you need to read the user's input from the keyboard.  In C, the keyboard input comes from a [File Descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) known as `stdin`.  To read from `stdin`, one option is to use [fscanf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm) as in  [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/C/File/fscanffprintfexample.htm).  That should get you going.  Good luck and happy reading.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I forgot about the quotation mark before Enter. I'm just having trouble figuring out how to read the user's input from the keyboard. If you can show me an example of a program where a user types in some numbers and how to calculate an answer using multiplication. Thank you in advance.